# When I open page "www.ru" with IE6 through Squid 2.7 I see offer to download "index.php". Why?

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I installed squid 2.7 stable 9 on Debian 6 in generic config. When I open page "www.ru" with IE6 through Squid 2.7 I see offer to download "index.php". When I open this page around proxy, everythink OK. Why it's so?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the browser receives wrong `Content-Type` in HTTP response header.